# How to safely start and stop an audio stream in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

How do you start and stop an audio stream, so that you can optionally start it again, in Javascript?

To start the stream, I'm using:

```
running = false;

function handleAudioStream(stream){
    let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    let source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    let processor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);

    source.connect(processor);
    processor.connect(audioCtx.destination);

    processor.onaudioprocess = function(event) {
        console.log('processing audio');
        if (!running) {
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                if (track.readyState == 'live' && track.kind === 'audio') {
                    track.stop();
                }
            });
            return;
        }
        var audioData = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        do_stuff(audioData);
    };
    processor.connect(audioCtx.destination);
}

function start_audio(){
    running = true;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: false
    }).then(handleAudioStream);
}

function stop_audio(){
    running = false;
}
```

As recommended in other questions, to stop the stream, I'm using a global flag to trigger the calling of the [stop method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop) on each track from within the stream callback.

However, this doesn't seem to work very well. This does stop audio data from being available, but the `processor.onaudioprocess` callback continues to get called, consuming a massive amount of CPU.

Also, if I run `start_audio()` again, it doesn't re-start the audio. The browser just seems to ignore it and the audio context never re-initializes correctly.

What am I doing wrong? How do I cleanly stop an audio stream so that I can later re-start it?